# Find a plane that passes through the line $x-1=\frac{y-3}{-2}=z$ and is perpendicular to the plane $x+y-2z=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm mostly having trouble with the first part. How do I make sure the plane passes through the given line, $x-1=\frac{y-3}{-2}=z$?

The second part seems easy enough; just set the dot product of the two planes' normal vectors equal to $0$, and solve for the normal vector of the first plane.

Comment: find two point of this line ! like this $(1,3,0)$ or $(2,1,1)$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash Can you elaborate? What should I do after finding the two points?

Comment: to write a plane equation ,we need a point and a normal vector . so you have to find them . you can find a normal vector for that plane , by cross multiplying of $(1,-2,1),parallel of line  $ ",parallel of line" and $(1,1,-2)$normal vector of $ x+y-2z=1$  .  Then you have a normal vector , so now write a plane by normal vector and one point of line (because the plane contain line )

Comment: @wowlolbrommer You can find the formula of a plane from three points only if the points are non-collinear. This isn't the case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line has parametric equations $x=1+t, y=3-2t, z=t$, so $\vec{a}=\langle1,-2,1\rangle$ is parallel to the line.

If $\vec{n}$ is a normal vector to the plane, then $\vec{n}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{a}$ and to $\vec{b}=\langle1,1,-2\rangle$, so

$\vec{n}$ is a multiple of $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\langle3,3,3\rangle$.  Therefore you can take $\vec{n}=\langle1,1,1\rangle$, and use the fact that

the plane passes through the point $(1,3,0)$ on the given line.

Comment: Thanks, your answer and darya's comment together made things clear for me. There's a small typo though- $x=1+2t$ should be $x=1+t$

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and the correction.